# spyOn encodeURI function in jasmine and typescript unit tests

Tags: typescript, jasmine

I want to test if the encodeURI function have been called with 'my#String'

```
let encoded: string = encodeURI( 'my#String' );
```

In tests, what I need to do is just to spy encodeURI function and check if it's have been called with the string, any Idea?

```
    it('should call encodeURI', function(){
        //1.Spy encodeURI here 
        //2.Execute the function here
        expect( encodeURI ).toHaveBeenCalledWith('my#String');

    });
```

Comment: tried spy = jasmine.createSpy('encodeURI'); and expect( spy ).toHaveBeenCalledWith('my#String'); but no luck

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass your test object to spy, then it can spy on it.

e.g.

```
var sut = new TestOb();
...
var spy = spyOn(sut, 'encodeURI');

it('should call encodeURI', function() {
    sut.someTestMethod();
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('my#String');
});
```

Comment: Did you try debugging it in a browser? What happens when you step in your function, does it go to your own implementation, or does it go to Jasmine's spy?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
it('should call encodeURI', () => {
 
    spyOn(window, 'encodeURI').and.callThrough();
    expect(window.encodeURI).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

});
```